# REST APIs - create an API to duplicate an element under another resource

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I've a couple of resources, let's say `/a` and `/b`, both of them have a same type of resource under them, like `/a/:id/c` and `/b/:id/c`.

I want that end users can duplicate these resources between the two of them. At the moment they should do a **GET** call on `/a/:id/c/:id`, strip away the data referred to the `/a` resource, remove the id, and do a **POST** on `/b/:id/c`.

There is a better way? Like creating a **POST** on `/b/:id/c` with a `duplicate` property in the body?

`c` can or cannot have the same id in the two resources

A real example from the real world:
StackExchange has multiple portal, and you can duplicate profile between them.

For the sake of discussion, let's say we have *stackexchange.com/sites/stackoverflow* and my user is reachable by *stackexchange.com/sites/stackoverflow/users/2586392*.

I now want to login to askubuntu, and my user is created under *stackexchange.com/sites/askubuntu/users/85484*. There is any POST call to duplicate all my elements (but the ID) or is the end user which does GET (on old resource) + POST (on the new one)?

Comment: Why is linking to the user resource not an option?

Comment: The question is unclear. What's the problem?

Comment: @RomanVottner because in a second moment the resource can be patched and so they can differ.

Comment: @Justas what's the best way to design an API which says 'fill your data with this other resource'? Like a POST, but with an empty body with only  field that say where you want to copy the fields from

Comment: What prevents you from simply sending a POST request with empty body? POST has no specifiy semantic other than it is up to the server what it is using for. But I don't get the needs of your use case TBH. As you pointed out stackexchange portals in your post, the users for each portal share common data but also have distinct one (like the posts or rep). You therefore may use the same user object which embedds (JSON-HAL f.e.) state for the respective portal which are independent of other portal information and let the client decide what data it wants or return data only for the respective portal